# Why do i get a Syntax error using exec()?

Tags: python

This function grabs a python script from a paste on pastebin with the title `py_0001`, when the execution reaches the `try: except:`  it throws an error
`SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

If you copy value of `script_` and declare it as a string variable it executes without any errors

The function works fine until it reaches the error handling part

```
def get_script():
    ''' grabs python script from pastebin '''
    reg_ = r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*\">py_0001'
    resp = requests.get(url='https://pastebin.com/u/'+usr_name)
    path = re.findall(reg_ , str(resp.content) , re.MULTILINE)  
    url2 = "https://pastebin.com/raw/"+ str(path[0]).replace('">py_0001' , '')
    resp2 = requests.get(url2)
    script_ = str(resp2.content)[2:-1]
    print (script_)


  
    try:
      exec(script_)
    except:
      print ("3rr0r")
```

This is the output of the paste on pastebin

```
import os\r\nimport time \r\nimport random \r\n \r\ndef fun_9991():\r\n    ## a simple code example to test \r\n    for i in range (0 , 10 ):\r\n        print ( " loop count {} , random number is {} , time is {} ".format(i , random.randrange(10) , int(time.time()/1000)))\r\n    print ("loop reached the end")\r\n    \r\n \r\nif __name__ == "__main__":\r\n    fun_9991()\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

Comment: what are you trying to `exec`? is it the complete python script?

Comment: You should pretty much never call `str()`  on a bytes object. Use `.decode` instead.

Comment: i am trying to execute the last bit of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is calling `str()` on a bytes object. NEVER call `str()` on a bytes object to convert it to a string, since it behaves like `repr()`. Simply using [2:-1] will only remove the quotes but not undo escaping other special characters.

You can do this:

```
script_ = resp2.content.decode('utf-8')
```

Or this:

```
script_ = resp2.text
```

Also, executing random code from the internet is an *incredibly* bad idea.

Comment: I am creating this random code and i am using a VM to test it out